# Dynamic views in Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a RecyclerView with CardView as its items.

Below is the layout for my main activity.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.personal.newz.ui.MainActivity">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/rv"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And below is the layout for my recycler view items

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/vertical_guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="2 hours ago" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/source_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/date_tv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/date_tv"
            tools:text="BBC News" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headline_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/vertical_guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date_tv"
            tools:text="Apple admits slowing down older iphones" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:maxLines="4"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/date_tv"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/vertical_guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headline_tv"
            tools:text="Customers have long suspected iPhones slow down over time. Now, Apple has confirmed some models do." />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/article_image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".7"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/vertical_guideline"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/source_tv"
            tools:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bookmark_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bookmark"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/share_image"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vertical_guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/article_image"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/share_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/share_icon"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bookmark_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/article_image" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Now when I first start my app the individual cardview's width don't match to the parent and kind of behave like their width is wrap content. After a few seconds the width of all the cardviews adjusts itself to match the parent.

[image: This is the initial width of the cardviews.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConstraintLayout` does not actually support `match_parent` for its children. If you try to use `match_parent`, *sometimes* it will work, and sometimes it will not. Android Studio is also sort of weird about `match_parent`, and sometimes will allow it and sometimes will automatically replace it with a hardcoded value that matches the last emulator you ran. Regardless, do not use `match_parent` for children of a `ConstraintLayout`.

Instead of **`android:layout_width="match_parent"`**, use this:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
```

Instead of **`android:layout_height="match_parent"`**, use this:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

When I make these changes to your `RecyclerView` tag, the problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks @Ben. I tried your suggestion and it worked for me too. So are you also suggesting that we should never use match parent for constraint layout's children?

Comment: I am. Ctrl+f for `match_parent` on this page: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: Got it. Thanks again